Add a 'data-x' attribute to a <form> with simple_form?
I'm trying to add a Stimulus handler to all forms:
<form data-controller="ajax-errors"></form>
I looked at the code in simple_form and the only option I see is to add a default_form_class
https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/main/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb
Is there a way to append a data attribute to every form without having to pass a custom data attribute to each one?
I tried appending it to wrapper_html on the default wrapper but it didnt work

If you want something to fire on every form submission in your app why not just add an event handler to the document which catches the event as it bubbles to the top of the DOM?

It appears that simple_form_for does not allow for default html options other than :class Source
That being said we should be able to hijack this implementation using a prepended module.
For Example something like the following (placed in an initializer) might work :
module SimpleFormDataExtension 
  DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {html: {data: {controller: "ajax-errors"}}
  def simple_form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
    super(record, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.deep_merge(options), &block) 
  end
end 

SimpleForm::ActionViewExtensions::FormHelper.prepend(SimpleFormDataExtension) 

